# CoreSpotlight contentDesciption with NSLocalizedString

Tags: ios, ios9, corespotlight

is it possible to localize the content description used in CSSearchableItemAttributeSet for Core Spotlight? I'm failing to do so, and I can't find information about it.

```
let attributeSet = CSSearchableItemAttributeSet(itemContentType: kUTTypeImage as String)

 attributeSet.contentDescription = NSLocalizedString("contentDescription", comment: "")
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `CSLocalizedString` for that. See link below:

https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/CoreSpotlight/Reference/CSLocalizedString_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/CSLocalizedString

Comment: Why do I need to use CSLocalizedString for this?